# Apache Tomcat Embedded Spring boot logs

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot

I have these access logs from Apache Tomcat Application server:

```
[05/Apr/2018:16:09:03 +0300] "GET MY_URL HTTP/1.1" 200 5442 138
[05/Apr/2018:16:09:06 +0300] "-" 400 - 0
```

I have hard time of reading it, what does "200 5442 138" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What ever logged in your tomcat logs are access logs which are logged whenever any url is invoked. What has to be printed in the logs are controlled based on the values configured in tomcat configuration file.

[05/Apr/2018:16:09:03 +0300] :- [Date Time and Timezone differnce from GMT]

"GET :- this is the http method which is invoked (GET, POST, PUT, HEAD, etc are the http methods)

MY_URL :- The URI which is invoked

HTTP/1.1" :- HTTP Version
 200 :- This is the http return code which says HTTP OK, there are other return codes 4xx, 5xx, 3xx etc..

5442 :- This is the content length of the response of the url invocation in bytes

138 :- This is the response time in milli seconds for retrieving the uri which is invoked.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Eby

Comment: Thanks, this helps me a lot!!! Also have you any Idea what can cause   "-" 400 - 0 ?

Comment: Http 400 is page not found. this means the end users got either a blank page as response and is a bad request so status code is 400 content length is zero hence a "-" and 0 is the reponse time to produce a blank response back to the end user.